# Videos in aframe on samsung internet

Tags: aframe, webvr, gear-vr

I know I should have limited expectations towards gearVr, as documented [here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/vr-headsets-and-webvr-browsers.html), but i need to make a site specifically for it.

Although primitives textured with images work like a charm, when i add a plane with a video texture, the lighting goes off on one eye, moreover playing the video on fusing is not working whatsoever. Here's the most simplified version of my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/aframevr/aframe/d47ce98/dist/aframe-master.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    AFRAME.registerComponent('vidtest', {
      init: function() {
        this.el.addEventListener('click',function(){
          document.querySelector('#vid').load();
          document.querySelector('#vid').play();
        });
      }
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <video id="vid" src="tlo1.mp4" autoplay="false" crossorigin playsinline webkit-playsinline>
      </a-assets>
      <a-plane vidtest position="0 1 -2" material="src:#vid"></a-plane>
      <a-camera>
        <a-entity cursor="fuse: true; fuseTimeout: 500"
            position="0 0 -1"
            geometry="primitive: ring; radiusInner: 0.02; radiusOuter: 0.03"
            material="color: black; shader: flat">
        </a-entity>
      </a-camera>
    </a-scene>

  </body>
</html>
```

Its live [here](http://gftruj.nazwa.pl/2/simplified.html).
I think it's ok, given the fact it works on android firefox, and on desktop chrome/firefox. Though it seems to have issues on android-chrome.

Btw I can make my site work on gear ONLY on the master build, earlier builds won't even let me enter vr-mode.

Anyone had these issues ? I tried adding gear controls there, internet://webvr-enable seem to do nothing. Can i open chrome or firefox on the gearVr ?

Comment: Hi Piotr. I've just tried replicating this, but I can't see the issue you describe in Samsung Internet for Gear VR v5.2. Which version are you using? If it looks like a browser problem perhaps you could write it up as an issue here?: https://github.com/SamsungInternet/support p.s. You can find the WebVR flag under internet://flags (https://webvr.rocks/samsung_internet).

Comment: Not sure the answer, but I don't know if `.load()` is needed to be called for the video, just `.play()` should work.

Comment: thanks for the replies, ill check my version and if play works properly once i get my hands on the gear i have at work